# onPongReceived is never called

Tags: android, websocket, androidasync-koush

My team is building an Android application that will use websockets to communicate with an existing backend. We chose to use the AndroidAsync by Koushik Dutta to handle this communication.
I would like to register a ping to be sent periodically, to check if the connection is still alive. I'm using Wireshark to check the network traffic. This is a screenshot of the result that Wireshark is showing:

[image: Wireshark screenshot]

From what I see here, I believe that the ping is being sent, and the pong is being received.
A snippet of my code is:

```
private void keepAlive() {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Pinging...");
            WebSocketHandler.this.webSocket.ping("LALALA");
        }
    };
    pingScheduledFuture = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, PING_PERIOD,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

The `onPongReceived` method just prints into Logcat

```
@Override
public void onPongReceived(String s) {
    // TODO here I'm aware if connection is still alive
    Log.d(TAG, "Pong received! " + s);
}
```

However, `Pong received!` is never printed! Also, if I put a breakpoint there, the app will never stop executing at that point
Anyone has any idea on what may I be missing here?
Best regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `AsyncSocket` but a quick google revealed that you have to register a callback `setPongCallback()` somewhere for your pong to be received. Are you doing this? You're not showing a lot of code.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I forgot to set the pongCallback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was extremely lame, but here's the solution. I forgot to set the callback to the websocket, like this:

```
WebSocketHandler.this.webSocket.setPongCallback(WebSocketHandler.this);
```

And then, the pongs were correctly received.